# No aop output using spring aop 2.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I'm reading Spring in Action and I'm trying to set an aop example.

```
package com.springinaction.chapter01.knight;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

public class KnightApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("knight.xml"));
        Knight knight = (Knight) factory.getBean("knight");
        knight.embarkOnQuest();
    }
}
```

The file KnightOfTheRoundTable.java:

```
package com.springinaction.chapter01.knight;

public class KnightOfTheRoundTable implements Knight {
    private String name;
    private Quest quest;

    public KnightOfTheRoundTable(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Object embarkOnQuest() throws QuestFailedException {
        //minstrel.singBefore(this);
        HolyGrail grail = (HolyGrail) quest.embark();
        //minstrel.singAfter(this);
        return grail;
    }

    public void setQuest(Quest quest) {
        this.quest = quest;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name;
    }
}
```

The file Minstrel.java:

```
package com.springinaction.chapter01.knight;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Minstrel {
    private static final Logger SONG = Logger.getLogger(Minstrel.class);

    public void singBefore(Knight knight) {
        SONG.info("Fa la la; Sir " + knight.getName() + " is so brave!");
        System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
    }

    public void singAfter(Knight knight) {
        SONG.info("Tee-hee-he; Sir " + knight.getName()
              + " did embark on a quest!");
    }
}
```

The output is as follows :

```
DEBUG ClassUtils - Class [org.apache.commons.collections.map.LinkedMap] or one of its dependencies is not present: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.map.LinkedMap
DEBUG ClassUtils - Class [edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap] or one of its dependencies is not present: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from file [C:\Users\Chris\workspace\chapter01\knight.xml]
DEBUG DefaultDocumentLoader - Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]
DEBUG PluggableSchemaResolver - Loading schema mappings from [META-INF/spring.schemas]
DEBUG PluggableSchemaResolver - Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
DEBUG DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader - Loading bean definitions
DEBUG XmlBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'knight'
DEBUG XmlBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'knight' with merged definition [Root bean: class [com.springinaction.chapter01.knight.KnightOfTheRoundTable]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireCandidate=true; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [C:\Users\Chris\workspace\chapter01\knight.xml]]
DEBUG XmlBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'knight' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG XmlBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'quest'
DEBUG XmlBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'quest' with merged definition [Root bean: class [com.springinaction.chapter01.knight.HolyGrailQuest]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireCandidate=true; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [C:\Users\Chris\workspace\chapter01\knight.xml]]
DEBUG XmlBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'quest' to allow for resolving potential circular references
```

File knight.xml :

```
<bean id="minstrel" class="com.springinaction.chapter01.knight.Minstrel" />
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="minstrel">
        <aop:pointcut id="questPointcut"
            expression="execution(* *.embarkOnQuest(..)) and target(bean)" />
        <aop:before method="singBefore" pointcut-ref="questPointcut"
            arg-names="bean" />
        <aop:after-returning method="singAfter"
            pointcut-ref="questPointcut" arg-names="bean" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
<bean id="quest" class="com.springinaction.chapter01.knight.HolyGrailQuest" />
<bean id="knight"
    class="com.springinaction.chapter01.knight.KnightOfTheRoundTable">
    <constructor-arg value="Bedivere" />
    <property name="quest" ref="quest" />
</bean>
```

The minstrel code is not invoked.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, your example is incomplete. I can't see any definition of `Knight` and `Quest` interface. I could guess, of cource, but still. The way you formatted your question is also not helping to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,

file knight.xml :

```
<bean id="minstrel" class="com.springinaction.chapter01.knight.Minstrel" />
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="minstrel">
        <aop:pointcut id="questPointcut"
            expression="execution(* *.embarkOnQuest(..)) and target(bean)" />
        <aop:before method="singBefore" pointcut-ref="questPointcut"
            arg-names="bean" />
        <aop:after-returning method="singAfter"
            pointcut-ref="questPointcut" arg-names="bean" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
<bean id="quest" class="com.springinaction.chapter01.knight.HolyGrailQuest" />
<bean id="knight"
    class="com.springinaction.chapter01.knight.KnightOfTheRoundTable">
    <constructor-arg value="Bedivere" />
    <property name="quest" ref="quest" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here: 
1. Your logs contain `ClassNotFoundException` for classes `org.apache.commons.collections.map.LinkedMap` and `edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` wich is quite strange, because your code doesn't mention none of these classes, and Spring, as far as I know, also doesn't use them. To fix this exeptions, you need to add Apache `common-collections.jar` and `backport-util-concurrent.jar` libraries to your classpath. 

2. You use `BeanFactory` implementation instead of `ApplicationContext` implementation. According to Spring documentation BeanFactory implementations by default doesn't support AOP. Here is quote from there:
*A BeanFactory pretty much just instantiates and configures beans. An ApplicationContext also does that, and it provides the supporting infrastructure to enable lots of enterprise-specific features such as transactions and AOP.*

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem while reading about Spring AOP. Then I added the dependency in my pom.xml (I used spring with maven) and then it started working.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>aspectj</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
<version>1.5.4</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note: I used following code for loading spring configuration file.

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
```